# Finding the Max() Datetime Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, max

I have a question about using dates on pandas. 
In the CSV I am importing (if I ordering it), I will find that the maximum date is **10/09/2019  18:22:00**

Immediately after importing (still as object), the date that appears is **31/12/2018 12:05**.

And if I convert in this way to date and time:

`df['Data_Abertura_Processo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data_Abertura_Processo'])`

the value changes to: **Timestamp('2019-12-08 18:40:00')**.

How do I get the maximum date I find into the CSV by filtering in Excel itself?
Today I'm using:

`df['Data_Abertura_Processo'].max()`

Am I wrong in converting or using max ()?

Comment: The correct answer:


df['Data_Abertura'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data_Abertura'])
df['Data_Abertura'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data_Abertura'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
print(df['Data_Abertura'].min(), df['Data_Abertura'].max())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Data_Abertura_Processo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data_Abertura_Processo'],format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Make sure that your datetimes have all the same format.

Comment: Thank you PySeeker.. I've tried but now I found a way... Tks anyaway!!! :)